# Recursive Struct Typedef

Tags: c, struct

I'm creating the following struct pointer type:

```
typedef struct hashmap_item {
    hashmap_item_t prev;
    hashmap_item_t next;
    char* key;
    void* value;
    int time_added;
} *hashmap_item_t;
```

But I get the following error:

```
hashmap.h:5: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before "hashmap_item_t"
```

I'm assuming this is because the struct I'm defining contains itself as a field. How can I avoid this? Is there a way to forward-declare structs?

Thanks!

Comment: I would like the struct to contain hashmap_item_t's, which are pointers to hashmaps... is the only way to get it to work to do hashmap_item* as the field?

Answer (score 5):

When the compiler comes to the declaration of the `prev`  and `next` members, it tries to find the identifier `hashmap_item_t`, but it hasn't been declared yet. In C all identifiers *must* be declared before they can be used.

You have two choices: Either declare the `typedef` *before* the structure (yes it's legal); Or use a structure declaration such as:

```
typedef struct hashmap_item {
    struct hashmap_item *prev;
    struct hashmap_item *next;
    char* key;
    void* value;
    int time_added;
} *hashmap_item_t;
```

Answer (score 4):

you can't do like that... you can

```
// C,C++ allows pointers to incomplete types.
typedef struct hashmap_item *hashmap_item_t;

struct hashmap_item {
    hashmap_item_t prev;
    hashmap_item_t next;
    char* key;
    void* value;
    int time_added;
};  // Till this point the structure is incomplete.
```

When the compiler starts parsing your code, It will find `hashmap_item_t` has not been declare anywhere previously. So, it will throw a error message.

```
typedef struct hashmap_item {
    hashmap_item_t prev; // Compiler was unable to find 'hashmap_item_t'
    hashmap_item_t next; // Compiler was unable to find 'hashmap_item_t'
    char* key;
    void* value;
    int time_added;
} *hashmap_item_t;// But 'hashmap_item_t' identifier appears here!!!
```

Comment: Or else use the structure declaration as suggested by @Joachim Pileborg